# Angularjs How to get value of input[text] in controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I want to get value of input[text] in my controller when data is changed as this source code:

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
    app.controller('ScanDataCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.getScannedData = function () {
            console.log($scope.formScanData.scanDataIReceipt);
        };
    });
    app.directive('scanDataBScan', function ($mdDialog, $sce, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('click', function () {
                    scope.getScannedData();
                    // => the value always undefined
                });
            }
        };
    }); 
});

<div ng-controller="ScanDataCtrl">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-inline formScanData" name="formScanData">
        <input ng-model="formScanData.scanDataIReceipt" type="text" required>
       <md-input-container>
            <md-button ng-model="scanDataBScan" class="md-raised md-primary scanDataBScan">Scan</md-button>
        </md-input-container>
    </form>
</div>
```

the result of this source code is always undefine

Please help me.
If I ask wrong or bad with my English, I am sorry.

Thank you!

Comment: have you tried console.log($scope.scanDataIReceipt); with 
<input ng-model="scanDataIReceipt" type="text" required>

Comment: Is the event on the button is triggered? I don't think... try: <md-button ng-click="getScannedData()" class="md-raised md-primary scanDataBScan">Scan</md-button>

Comment: app.directive('scanDataBScan', function ($mdDialog, $sce, $http) {
 return {
  restrict: 'C',
  link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
   element.on('click', function () {

    console.log($scope.formScanData.scanDataIReceipt); // value is valid
   
    scope.getScannedData();
    // => the value always undefined
   });
  }
 };
});

Answer (score 0):

Use the `ng-change` directive:

```
 <input ng-model="formScanData.scanDataIReceipt" type="text" 
        ng-change="getScannedData()" required>
```

For more information, see [AngularJS ng-change Directive API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange).

Answer (score 0):

```
(function () {
    'use strict';
    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngMaterial']);
    app.controller('ScanDataCtrl', function ($scope) {
        $scope.getScannedData = function (data) {
            console.log(data);
        };
    });
    app.directive('scanDataBScan', function ($mdDialog, $sce, $http) {
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
                element.on('click', function () {
                    scope.getScannedData();
                    // => the value always undefined
                });
            }
        };
    }); 
});

<div ng-controller="ScanDataCtrl">
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" class="form-inline formScanData" name="formScanData">
        <input ng-model="formScanData.scanDataIReceipt" type="text" required>
       <md-input-container>
            <md-button ng-model="scanDataBScan" ng-click="getScannedData(formScanData.scanDataIReceipt)" class="md-raised md-primary scanDataBScan">Scan</md-button>
        </md-input-container>
    </form>
</div>
```